# How do i "import" a java file into another file

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I'm currently having trouble with my program, what I'm trying to do is to "import" a file that contains my variables into my main Java file, so that it recognizes the variables without adding them into the main file.

I created a `.java` file called Variables, this code is inside:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package destinytextgame;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author 30136246
 */
public class Variables {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String first_name;
    int age;

}
```

What I want to do is to be able to make the main Java file that I'm using to code my program recognize the code in the `Variables.java` file. When I tried it without any additional code, it kept popping up with an error, saying that first_name isn't defined. Could anyone be of assistance?

Comment: Please share the code for main java file

Comment: Those are non-static variables, so you'd need an instance of `Variable` on which to access them.

Comment: You don't - that's not how Java works. If you import the `Variables` class, that just means you can use the name `Variables` without fully-qualifying it; you'd still need to create an *instance* of `Variables`.

Comment: You normally don't have to import classes in the `java.lang` package such as `String`. I feel there's something you didn't post/tell us.

Comment: You don't have to explicitly import classes in `java.lang`, but you can't define classes in that package either.

Comment: use static String first_name; and refer using Variables .first_name

Comment: There is not much we can do without seeing your `Variables` class. Does the class have empty constructor or not? Where  and how are the variables defined? We can only guess.

Comment: The question is why you want to import variables anyway. Java is not C and does not have the concept of just "including" code without context or structure. Each object  should have its own variables. Although you can use public static variables from other classes, it is seriously not recommended to do so (except when they are constants). So what are you trying to achieve by doing this? Perhaps we'll be able to give you the appropriate Java way of achieving the same goal.

Comment: RealSkeptic - What i had hoped to achieve from doing this is for the program to store the input for the intended variable (first_name) into an external file if that is possible. I may of made it more complicated by trying this way of doing it.

Comment: Do you mean some kind of a properties file?

Comment: Almost, However thanks to Meskobalazs suggestion below, i was able to get my intended result. Thank you to all the others for trying to help me as well, all input was greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an *instance* of Variables class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Variables variables = new Variables();
    System.out.println("Please enter your first name:");
    variables.first_name = variables.input.next();
    System.out.println("Hi " + variables.first_name + "!");
}
```

Comment: This worked, i added a System out to test to see if it was stored inside that variable and it was, Thank you meskobalaz, this has solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

A few things that you may want to try:

Make the variables `public static` if you only want one instance of them.

Instantiate your variables class `Variables vars = new Variables();` and then call the variables from the instance `vars.first_name = "First Name";`

If you are using the instance method then i would suggest using [Getters and Setters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html)

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) may also help you in understanding how to get the class variables better.

**Doing it the static way:**

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Variables.first_name = "Hello, you.";
        System.out.println("first_name: " + Variables.first_name);
    }

    private static class Variables {

        private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        public static String first_name;
        public static int age;
    }
}
```

**Doing it the OOP way:**

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Variables var = new Variables();

        var.setFirst_name("First Name Here");
        System.out.println(var.getFirst_name());
    }

    private static class Variables {

        private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        public String first_name;
        public int age;

        public String getFirst_name() {
            return first_name;
        }

        public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
            this.first_name = first_name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
}
```